# How to implement frequent start/stop of a thread (QThread)

Tags: multithreading, qt, qthread

I need to start and stop a thread very frequently using push button..I am using Qt. Recently I learned to create a QObject of the worker and move it to the object of the QThread as the correct way of implementing threads in Qt. Following is my implementation...

**Worker.h**

```
class worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit worker(QObject *parent = 0);
    void StopWork();
    void StartWork();
    bool IsWorkRunning();

signal:
    void SignalToObj_mainThreadGUI();

public slots:
    void do_Work();

private:
    void Sleep();

    volatile bool running,stopped;
    QMutex mutex;
    QWaitCondition waitcondition;
};
```

**Worker.cpp**

```
 worker::worker(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),stopped(false),running(false)
{
}

void worker::do_Work()
{
    running = true;
    while(!stopped)
    {
        emit SignalToObj_mainThreadGUI();
        Sleep();
    }
}

void worker::Sleep()
{
    mutex.lock();
    waitcondition.wait(&mutex,10);
    mutex.unlock();
}

void worker::StopWork()
{
    mutex.lock();
    stopped = true;
    running = false;
    mutex.unlock();
}

void worker::StartWork()
{
    mutex.lock();
    stopped = false;
    running = true;
    mutex.unlock();
}

bool worker::IsWorkRunning()
{
    return running;
}
```

**MainWindow.h**

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_push_to_start_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_push_to_stop_clicked();

private:

    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    worker *myWorker;
    QThread *WorkerThread;
};
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    myWorker = new worker;
    WorkerThread = new QThread;
    myWorker.moveToThread(WorkerThread);

    QObject::connect(WorkerThread,SIGNAL(started()),myWorker,SLOT(do_Work()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_push_to_start_clicked()
{
    if(!myWorker.IsWorkRunning())
       {
         myWorker->StartWork();
         WorkerThread->start();
       }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_push_to_stop_clicked()
{
  if(myWorker.IsWorkRunning())
     {
       myWorker->StopWork();
       WorkerThread->quit();
     }
}
```

Initially the application works fine but after some operations of the push button to turn the working of the thread on and off the following error comes up...

**QObject::killTimers(): timers cannot be stopped from another thread**

I am quite puzzled at this error...do I need to implement the start/stop functions as signals and slots rather than member functions of the class?

Comment: Try not to call start() and quit() on your thread. Once you move your worker object to a thread, you should just control worker directly. start() and quit() are only for initiating and shutting down the thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't start and stop `WorkerThread`.  Just leave it running.  Also, move your `StartWork()` and `StopWork()` methods to the public slots section.  You really don't need the mutex at all.

**Worker.h**

```
class worker : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit worker(QObject *parent = 0);

signal:
  void SignalToObj_mainThreadGUI();
  void running();
  void stopped();

public slots:
  void StopWork();
  void StartWork();

private slots:
  void do_Work();

private:
  volatile bool running,stopped;
};
```

**Worker.cpp**

```
worker::worker(QObject *parent) :
  QObject(parent), stopped(false), running(false)
{}

void worker::do_Work()
{
  emit SignalToObj_mainThreadGUI();

  if ( !running || stopped ) return;

  // do important work here

  // allow the thread's event loop to process other events before doing more "work"
  // for instance, your start/stop signals from the MainWindow
  QMetaObject::invokeMethod( this, "do_Work", Qt::QueuedConnection );
}

void worker::StopWork()
{
  stopped = true;
  running = false;
  emit stopped();
}

void worker::StartWork()
{
  stopped = false;
  running = true;
  emit running();
  do_Work();
}
```

**MainWindow.h**

```
namespace Ui {
  class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MainWindow();

signals:
  void startWork();
  void stopWork();

private slots:
  void on_pushButton_push_to_start_clicked();
  void on_pushButton_push_to_stop_clicked();

private:
  Ui::MainWindow *ui;
  worker *myWorker;
  QThread *WorkerThread;
```

};

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);

  myWorker = new worker;
  WorkerThread = new QThread;
  myWorker.moveToThread(WorkerThread);

  connect( this, SIGNAL(startWork()), myWorker, SLOT(StartWork()) );
  connect( this, SIGNAL(stopWork()), myWorker, SLOT(StopWork()) );
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_push_to_start_clicked()
{
  emit startWork();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_push_to_stop_clicked()
{
  emit stopWork();
}
```

Comment: Great answer thanks! a little follow up tho, say you have that do_Work function that is while(loop) how can I interrupt that action? I noticed that QueuedConnection wont stop the loop while its being processed so I guess I have to somehow check it myself?

Comment: @Dariusz : You wouldn't need a `while` loop in this case.  `do_Work` is invoked continuously (asynchronously) until the state of either `running` or `stopped` is toggled. So, just put the body of your `while` loop into the `do_Work` method, and use a flag (as in the answer) to break out of the "loop" when desired.

Comment: do we need `volatile` qualifier for `running` and `stopped`?

Comment: @DrobotViktor, no.  `volatile` isn't necessary.  I just copy/pasted from the question and didn't think to take it out.  I start/stop the worker via queued sig/slot connections, so access is serialized by the `WorkerThread` event loop.