# Qt - Simple example using threads controlled by push buttons

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I have been trying to get this simple example using threads activated by pushbuttons to work. It is based off of the solution in the question below:

[How to implement frequent start/stop of a thread (QThread)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051276/how-to-implement-frequent-start-stop-of-a-thread-qthread)

The main differences between the example solution above and my code below are:

1. I used a QWidget instead of MainWindow
2. I changed the name of signals for clarity
3. My code contains debugging information
4. I experimented with eliminating the signals created by worker as the didn't appear to do anything

It appears that the start/stop signals are not triggering their corresponding slots, but I am not experienced enough to troubleshoot why.

Additionally, I am unsure of the purpose of the signal:

> SignalToObj_mainThreadGUI()

Is that just something that could be used and is not?

I have been trying to get this code to work for some time, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**main.cpp**

> ```
> #include "threadtest.h"
> #include <QApplication>
>
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
> {
>     QApplication a(argc, argv);
>     ThreadTest w;
>     w.show();
>
>     return a.exec(); 
> }
> ```

**threadtest.h**

> ```
> #include <QWidget>
> #include <QThread>
> #include "worker.h"     
>
> namespace Ui 
> {
>     class ThreadTest;
> }
>
> class ThreadTest : public QWidget
> {
>     Q_OBJECT
>
> public:
>     explicit ThreadTest(QWidget *parent = 0);
>     ~ThreadTest();
>
> signals:
>     void startWorkSignal();
>     void stopWorkSignal();
>
>
> private slots:
>     void on_startButton_clicked();
>     void on_stopButton_clicked();
>
> private:
>     Ui::ThreadTest *ui;
>     worker *myWorker;
>     QThread *WorkerThread;
> };
> ```

**threadtest.cpp**

> ```
> #include "threadtest.h"
> #include "ui_threadtest.h"
>
> ThreadTest::ThreadTest(QWidget *parent) :
> QWidget(parent),
> ui(new Ui::ThreadTest) 
> {
>     ui->setupUi(this);
>
>     myWorker = new worker;
>     WorkerThread = new QThread;
>     myWorker->moveToThread(WorkerThread);
>
>     connect(this,
>             SIGNAL(startWorkSignal()),
>             myWorker,
>             SLOT(StartWork())
>             );
>
>     connect(this,
>             SIGNAL(stopWorkSignal()),
>             myWorker,
>             SLOT(StopWork())
>             );
>
>     //Debug
>     this->dumpObjectInfo();
>     myWorker->dumpObjectInfo(); 
> }
>
> ThreadTest::~ThreadTest() 
> {
>     delete ui; 
> }
>
> void ThreadTest::on_startButton_clicked() 
> {
>     qDebug() << "startwork signal emmitted";
>     emit startWorkSignal(); 
> }
>
> void ThreadTest::on_stopButton_clicked() 
> {
>     qDebug() << "stopwork signal emmitted";
>     emit stopWorkSignal(); 
> }
> ```

**worker.h**

> ```
> #include <QObject>
> #include <QDebug>
>
> class worker : public QObject {
>     Q_OBJECT 
> public:
>     explicit worker(QObject *parent = 0);
>     ~worker();
>
> signals:
>     void SignalToObj_mainThreadGUI();
>     //void running();
>     //void stopped();
>
> public slots:
>     void StopWork();
>     void StartWork();
>
> private slots:
>     void do_Work();
>
> private:
>     volatile bool running, stopped; 
> };
> ```

**worker.cpp**

> ```
> #include "worker.h"
>
> worker::worker(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent), stopped(false),
> running(false) 
> {
>     qDebug() << "running: " << running;
>     qDebug() << "stopped: " << stopped; 
>
> }
>
>
> worker::~worker() {}
>
> void worker::do_Work() 
> {
>     qDebug() << "inside do Work";
>     emit SignalToObj_mainThreadGUI();
>
>     if (!running || stopped) return;
>
>     // actual work here
>     /*
>     for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
>     {
>         qDebug() << "count: " + i;
>     }
>     */
>     QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "do_Work", Qt::QueuedConnection); 
> }
>
> void worker::StopWork() 
> {
>     qDebug() << "inside StopWork";
>     stopped = true;
>     running = false;
>
>     //emit stopped(); 
> }
>
> void worker::StartWork() 
> {
>     qDebug() << "inside StartWork";
>     stopped = false;
>     running = true;
>
>     //emit running();
>     do_Work(); 
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write

```
WorkerThread->start();
```

Or you can use the thread of the ThreadTest object instead the WorkerThread (in this case the WorkerThread is needless):

```
 myWorker->moveToThread(thread()); // this->thread
```

Answer (score 1):

The slots are not triggered, because you have moved myWork to the thread WorkerThread, but didnot run an event loop in that thread. In threadtest.cpp, add

```
WorkerThread .start();
```

after

```
myWorker = new worker;
WorkerThread = new QThread;
myWorker->moveToThread(WorkerThread);
```